# Unable to expose docker LoadBalancer service

Tags: windows, docker, powershell, kubernetes

I am trying to deploy a docker image which is in public repository. I am trying to create a loadbalancer service, and trying to expose the service in my system ip address, and not 127.0.0.1.
I am using a windows 10 , and my docker has WSL2 instead of hyper-v.

Below is my .yaml file. So, the service inside will run in port 4200, so to avoid any kind of confusion I was keeping all the ports in 4200.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hoopla
spec:
  selector:
    app: hoopla
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 4200
      targetPort: 4200
  clusterIP: 10.96.1.3
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: 192.168.0.144
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: hoopla
  name: hoopla
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: hoopla
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: hoopla
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: pubrepo/myimg:latest
        name: hoopla
        ports:
        - containerPort: 4200
```

Can anybody help me here to understand what mistake I am making. I basically want to expose this on my system IP address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `loadBalancer` service type require a cloud provider's load Balancer ( https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/ )

```
LoadBalancer: Exposes the Service externally using a cloud provider's load balancer. NodePort and ClusterIP Services, to which the external load balancer routes, are automatically created
```

If you want to expose your service to your local machine, use kubernetes service `nodePort` type for example, and if you just want to test your webapp, you can use the kubernetes service `clusterIp` type and make a port-forward, for example with your clusterIp service:

```
kubectl port-forward svc/hoopla 4200:4200
```

Comment: Hi , thank you for the reply. So if I use nodeport, I will be able to access the service via system ip address and not the localhost?

Comment: You will be able to access it through localhost, however if you open your system ports (firewalling) you will be able to access it through ip address :)

Comment: You don't necessarily require a Cloud Provider's Load Balancer to use the eponym Kubernetes Service. The name was wrongly chosen by the k8s team.
 
However, adding a NodePort is what is indeed missing from your config. Select a NodePort between 30000 and 32767 and input it in your .yaml file. Then you can access your Pod from <IP>:<NODE_PORT>.

Comment: For the LoadBalancer type of kubernetes service in deed you need an external cloud provider loadbalancing service. For nodePort and clusterIp types no need :)

Comment: Hi everyone, thank you for all your answer, I was indeed wasting my time through LoadBalancer approach, so thank you @bguess for helping me out here. I removed the service from my deployment file, and then 
```kubectl expose deployment-name --type=NodePort --port=<port>
```
then I opened another power window, there I did port-forward :

```kubectl port-forward service/deployment-name --address=<system_IP_address> <port>:<port>```
So then it started to work.

Comment: @bguess , which ip address are u refereing to ? when I expose the deployment as a service through nodeport, then a Ip address I can see when I do a ```kubectl get service/service-name``` , there I can use that ```<service-name-IP-address>:<NodePort-port-value>``` to access my service?

Comment: OH, if you can access you service, then its great ! hahaha